# Помогите разобраться с лямбда выражением

Tags: лямбда-выражение

Есть лист products и удаление по имени, подскажите пожалуйста что такое product!

```
products.removeIf(product -> product.getName().equals("Какое-то имя"));
```

Comment: это один элемент из списка продуктов.

Comment: Это типа как счетчик в циле?

Answer (score 1):

Под капотом метод `removeIf` использует цикл. И, если не углубляться, то будет обычный цикл `foreach`

```
for(Product product : products) {
    // тут логика
}
```

Вот `product` - элемент списка на каждой итерации.

Answer (score 0):

`product` - это переменная

лямбда-выражение можно было бы записать как:

```
function(product) {
    return product.getName().equals("Какое-то имя");
}
```

т.е. для каждого элемента из массива products будет вызвана функция указанная выше в качестве параметра в которую передается этот элемент массива

и если функция вернет `true`, т.е. если будет выполнено условие `product.getName().equals("Какое-то имя")`, то элемент будет удален из массива

т.е. по сути на выходе получится список элементов у которых некоторый параметр `name` равен `"Какое-то имя"`